# Removing Multilevel Index over multiple excel sheets Python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm preparing some data for a database. The first part is to convert the multilevel indexing to a single concatenated column. So far, I can do this over excel sheets with the same formats.

What I want to do is write one script that will go through each excel file, over all the sheets within them, looking for certain keywords to start the indexing.

So far I have had to make a few different scripts for each excel workbooks layout... I have a lot of files and I feel like there has to be a better way!

Any ideas of how to go about this, or has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed information about the structure of the files and the desired output? Maybe some of your sample code and link to a sample file?

Regarding iterating over all the excel files this might help you, assuming you have all excel files you want to iterate over in one folder (and no other files):
`import os`
`os.chdir("path/to_your/directory")`
`files = os.listdir()`
`for file in files:`
`'your logic'`

Comment: thanks - I ended up figuring out this issue - but I created another! I'll post a ew question that is more complete for this new problem